# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "modorra", "muermo" y "sopor"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario-médico

[**Modorra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PV9CZFy) es:

> 5. f. Somnolencia, sopor profundo.

mientras que [**muermo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q0IZhpS) es:

> 2. m. coloq. Estado de aburrimiento y sopor.

y [**sopor**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YP48G2G) es:

> 1. m. Adormecimiento, somnolencia.

¿Qué diferencia hay entre ellas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Habría que ver las palabras en contexto. Hay palabras que aunque signifiquen casi lo mismo que otras no se utilizan en ciertos contextos o junto con ciertas otras palabras. Por ejemplo, *muermo* es una palabra coloquial y por lo tanto no se puede utilizar en un contexto de formalidad (de hecho no sólo es coloquial sino que además es dialectal; yo no la conocía).

*Modorra* no es exactamente coloquial pero puede aparecer en contextos informales, por ejemplo, en una conversación entre amigos. En mi experiencia la utilizaría para describir el sueño ligero que uno siente naturalmente luego de comer, o a la hora de la siesta en los lugares donde se practica esta costumbre. Metafóricamente se habla de la modorra de un pueblo a estas horas tempranas de la tarde.

*Sopor* es algo más formal. A mí me sugiere un adormecimiento provocado por el cansancio, por una enfermedad o por algún medicamento. *Sopor* también se usa para referirse a un lapso de tiempo. La expresión *sopor invernal* es sinónima de *hibernación*.

Answer (score 2):

Desde mi punto de vista, hoy día la palabra *muermo* se usa principalmente en su primera acepción: "Persona o cosa tediosa y aburrida". Así se pueden encontrar ejemplos como:

> *En España, hace 30 años, un hombre podía ser impunemente mujeriego, juerguista, infiel y apasionado. O por el contrario, sobrio, ponderado, sensible y leal, también impunemente y sin dar más explicaciones. Ya en el 2001, ese mismo hombre puede seguir siendo un vacilón o un muermo, y en teoría no pasa nada, pero en realidad en ninguno de los dos casos lo será ya impunemente.*
>
> Begoña Ameztoy, "Escuela de mujeres", 2001 (España).

Sin embargo, también es usada como sinónimo de sopor, aunque por mi apreciación diría que se usa en tono despectivo:

> *[...] en cambio, todo sugiere que una acogida favorable por parte de la Comunidad difícilmente levantaría la borrasca de profundidad necesaria para provocar una conversión, una regeneración a partir del muermo hispánico que actualmente puebla las mentes de esta sociedad.*
>
> Álvaro Fernández Suárez, "El pesimismo español", 1983 (España).

La palabra *sopor* hace referencia al mismo estado de adormecimiento, pero de forma neutra. Como nota, se dan como tres veces más casos de esta palabra que de *muermo* en el CREA. Un ejemplo:

> En verano el sol cae de lleno, hasta el mediodía, y el calor lo envuelve todo en un halo casi esotérico que invita al recogimiento, el sopor o la meditación...
>
> La Vanguardia, 16/08/1995 (España).

Termino con *modorra*, que es una versión exagerada del sopor, no en vano está definido como "sopor profundo", y se usa incluso en casos patológicos. Se usa en algunos lugares para expresar el sueño irrefrenable que entra sobre todo las tardes de primavera, o después de comer de forma abundante. Aunque veo en ejemplos del CREA que se usa también de forma similar a *muermo*, en plan despectivo:

> *Son personajes que pueden sacudir nuestra terrible modorra actual. Esa modorra que nos vuelve pasivos ante cualquier influencia, sea la que viene de la entontecedora televisión que padecemos o de la aburrida política que sufrimos, sin una verdadera oposición que la renueve.*
>
> El País, 02/02/1987 (España).

La *modorra* como *sopor* se usa para describir un sopor benigno, de ese en el cual no te importa caer preso:

> *Un domingo fui invitado a almorzar con ellos. En una mañana soleada, de ésas en que uno siente una grata modorra. De pronto, siento voces que se sobresaltan e interrumpen mi ensoñación.*
>
> La Época, 03/10/1997 (Chile).

Comment: Precisamente, modorra en Chile es ese sopor que te da después de almuerzo, cuando has ido al campo y te deslizas sin retorno hacia un sueño pesado e inevitable. Te pesan la cabeza, no articulas coherentemente, los ojos se ponen vidriosos e hinchados (tengo la impresión de que se relaciona con ácido úrico o con una subida/bajada de azúcar apotéosica).

Comment: En Chile se usa además: Soponcio (aunque significa 1. m. coloq. Desmayo, congoja.) y abotagamiento. Todo, obviamente, relacionado con comida y vino en exceso, provocando la modorra e igualándola con los anteriores a causa de lo repentino (la primera) o de la sensación general del cuerpo (el segundo).